# tableview refresh json feed

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to reload my app with new data from a JSON feed. i'd try;

```
- (void) Refresh {
[self performSelector:(@selector(refreshDisplay:)) withObject:(_tableView) afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

and

```
- (void)refreshDisplay:(UITableView *)tableView {

    [_tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Downloading the JSON:

```
     NSString *jsonString = [NSString 
                                stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:xmlDataUrl] 
                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                error:nil];

        SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];

        parser = nil;

        [self setTableData:nil];
        [self setTableData:[results objectForKey:@"feed"]];
```

But it's not reloading my new data from the JSON, does anyone know how i can update the tableview with new data i'm downloading from a online JSON feed? I need to delete the old data from the JSON feed and insert the new data.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? I dont see any code that suggests new code getting downloaded.

Comment: Not enough information. What's calling your 'Refresh' method and when? How does the JSON data actually get refreshed? How does the table read the JSON data? Have you isolated the problem? Make sure each piece works, isolate the problem, and then describe it.

Comment: Sorry @Colin and Dragon112 i edited the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your data is actually changing?  You could place some `NSLog`s in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to make sure it's getting called.  It seems like your issue is that you're simply telling it to refresh after half a second, and the data may not be loaded by then.  I suggest you put the `[tableView reloadData]` call in the method which actually finishes updating the data, so that you know it's done by the time you call it.

Note too that this method:

```
- (void)refreshDisplay:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [_tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

isn't needed.  First of all, it ignores the argument and calls `reloadData` on your ivar `_tableView`.  Secondly, if all you wanted to do was reload the data after half a second, you can call:

```
[_tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
```

Further, based on the fact that it's called `_tableView` if you have an `@synthesize tableView=_tableView` you're better off using `self.tableView` anywhere you can, as this avoids accessing the ivar directly and is considered "good form".

To reiterate, make sure your data source is actually updating the data before calling `reloadData` on the tableview.

### Edit

To your updated post, simply add `[self.tableView reloadData];` at the end of your JSON parsing code.

Comment: i placed the JSON in 'refreshDisplay:(UITableView *)tableView' with this line under it [self.tableView reloadData]; but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

That code will have the tableview retrieve the data its datasource object has to offer, but it doesn't do anything to reload from your feed. You need to make sure that the UITableViewDataSource object's methods are returning the data from the updated JSON feed. Your refreshDisplay method could tell the datasource to update itself from the JSON feed first before telling the table to reloadData.